# Is it normal for cats to eat grass?

Tags: cats, behavior

A lot of times, when my cat is in the garden, I've seen him eating blades of grass (maybe just chewing them, I'm not sure if he swallows).

Why does this happen? Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, quite normal.

Comment: Anecdotally, I've heard that a lot of cats do it. Not sure why though - I'll be interested to read the answers!

Comment: I have seen little pots of grass sold in pet stores specifically for cats.  While being sold in a pet store does not always equal a healthy choice, it does equal a strong market.

Comment: No idea why, but my cat's very fond of chewing on grass. He doesn't eat much, but it's a regular stop for him after leaving the house.

Comment: Yes, every time I clean the carpet, the cat is urged to eat grass and vomit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is normal! As someone said before it is frequent that cats do it for cleanse as their natural instinct tells them to do so.

However, from my experience, I can say that it is normal as long as it doesn't happen very frequently. If it happens like everyday on a regular basis it may be a problem and you should have your cat checked by a professional. Cats eat grass for cleanse but if its exaggerated it may indicate that the cat is having any related stomach/digestion issues. 
I would suggest that you take a closer look to the situation and see if your cat does it on a regular day basis or just a few times sporadically or every time he's in the garden - for this last one, if the cat isn't allowed in the garden that often, it shouldn't be a problem as the cat is eating grass when he only has access to it.
Other things to look into, would be:

- Any recent dramatic changes on its diet?
- Did it stop eating as much or over-eating recently?
- Is it vomiting? (not from the grass but from the food you give it

  - homemade or cat food)

Again, I repeat, this is from my personal experience and if nothing from the above applies then I believe your cat is just fine!

Never the less I "googled" a bit and come up w/ these links that I found to be quite helpful:

- http://www.petmd.com/cat/wellness/evr_ct_eating_grass
- http://www.catbehaviorassociates.com/why-do-cats-eat-grass/

Comment: It may be worth mentioning, that rabbits clean them selves like cats and eat hay, in part to help keep their digestive track clear. [See related](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-is-wool-block-in-rabbits)