# My rabbit is suffering with splayed front legs

Tags: rabbits

My rabbit is suffering with splayed legs. Both her front legs are splayed. Could u please suggest me how to get him to normal position. What treatment or any supplements / vitamin doses ?[image]

Comment: I don't know much about rabbits, but in a cat or dog, I don't think they could achieve that position unless their legs were broken or dislocated. I think you should bring your rabbit to the vet immediately.

Comment: I think your question is duplicate of [My question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7302/what-is-the-cause-of-splayed-spread-front-legs-in-an-older-rabbit) If you do not agree please indicate in your question how it is different and it can be repopened.