# Should I always take everyone to the vet?

Tags: health, multi-pet-families, travel

As a rule we all (pets and parents) go to the vet together. Everyone lives together and shares the same resources, so if one is sick, it seems reasonable to get everyone checked out.  If it's annual physical time, well everyone needs one.

If one has a physical issue that is not communicable like a [hair ball](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/692/) we still take the family group, for moral support during the trip and while waiting.

The only time everyone does not go, is if the pet does not have a partner (lives in a segregated area) and is going in for a follow up on a non-communicable issue.

Am I just being over cautious/sensitive?  Are there medical/psychological issues that make including or excluding everyone from a trip to the vet the better choice?

Comment: I think it can be seen as productive and counterproductive at the same time, productive: taking all of your pets constantly even if theyre not sick, can make them lose that "fright" from visiting the vet(i think, hopefully) and counterproductive cause there's no need to take healthy animals to an area that's mostly for sick ones; they might get sick just from visiting the vet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Medically**

I asked my vet about this once. He said that if an animal is exposed to a communicable disease but not showing symptoms, we should still not *treat* the animal for the disease. They may be able to fight it off themselves, and our intervention may interrupt their ability to do that. Additionally, the added stress of taking them to the vet may cause them to succumb to the illness faster, more severely, or even at all (if their body had otherwise been able to fight it off).

Generally, in these situations, if a communicable disease is known to be in the house and I call or stop by the vet and tell them "another animal is showing the same symptoms", they'll direct me to start treating them with the same treatment that the first animal got.

Additionally, the vet's office is a place for sick animals. There's always the chance that your healthy pets may pick up a new communicable disease while there.

**Psychologically**

I think this depends on species to some extent, and on the relationships between pets. Most cats get so stressed by travel and the vet, and they (tend to) not bond as tightly as dogs and rabbits. I take my cats to the vet individually.

For tightly bonded animals, I would weigh the medical issues and the stress of the trip against the stress of being separated from their companion.