# Rabbits and cats

Tags: cats, rabbits

I just got a rabbit about two weeks ago.  I've had my kitten for about three months/ The cat/kitten is six months old. They were fine together at first but now they seem to fight.  The cat chases the rabbit but the rabbit also chases the cat and the cat is pouncing on the rabbit. I was wondering what I could do to maybe stop the behavior of the cat trying to attack the rabbit, any suggestions to how to get them to get along?

Answer (score 1):

Your cat and rabbit should not be left alone unsupervised until they have learned to behave well with each other. Cats and rabbits can do very well together, but supervision is required when introducing any new members to a household.

See related [What should we look for in a kitty companion for our rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2219)