# Is there something wrong with my cat and rabbit's relationship?

Tags: cats, behavior, rabbits, aggression, play

I'm hoping someone can help me. I assume my rabbit has just formed a strong bond with my kitten, but just wanted another person's perspective on the matter.

So, my cat is only four months old. However, she has been with my rabbit since she was very little. Estimated at around 5-6 weeks, I found her abandoned covered in fleas and stone cold. She instantly took a liking to my rabbit upon first introductions; my rabbit is free roamed indoors. They were introduced in a mutual part of the house. At first, he was a little unsure of the kitten and expressed his dominance, a little growl here and there and the odd chasing around the house. However, he never expressed aggression. I've never left them alone unattended, they are quite attached to me and follow me around so they are together often.

However, as my cat has started getting bigger she has started wanting to initiate play with my rabbit. She likes to sit above him on an object and try to tap his head. Recently, I've noticed a change in my rabbit's behavior. He's gone from wanting to be dominant to submissive. He is a very big rabbit compared to her, so it's strange. He will let her climb all over him and try to get his ears. He'll just sit there and accept it, no grunts or growls. No attempting to bite. If he has enough he kind of just gets up and walks away. Although sometimes it's like she chases him afterward and tries to mount him. She hasn't shown any signs of aggression and he seems very happy and content. He still blinks and flops and seems to enjoy her company. My main worry was the weird turn to being submissive.

My question is, is this normal behavior, should I be worried, and how would you interpret this?

Answer (score 2):

Dominance signs in cats: cat wants to show how tall it is, starts to stretch the head up and wants to get above the opponent.

Dominance in rabbits: rabbit wants to be groomed, wants to get UNDER the opponent.

This is why rabbits and cats are this happy together :D each of them thinks "I am the dominant one" and wins the fight.

So how you described the behavior of your rabbit, it is still happy that the cat treats the rabbit's fur. Maybe from the rabbit's point of view the cat will not win an award for the best groomer, but the intention is what counts ;)

And the cat is happy that the rabbit accepts the lower position without any pressure, and the cat can satisfy its curiosity and instinct to play.

Have a look in this question, to get more information about rabbit-cat-relationship:
[What should we look for in a kitty companion for our rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/what-should-we-look-for-in-a-kitty-companion-for-our-rabbit)

Answer (score -2):

In general, rabbits are prey animals to cats so your cat is doing regular cat behavior. The rabbit is afraid to fight back because the cat will have the upper hand in a fight. I would expect this as normal behaviour between prey animals and predators.

But most of the time, cats that live indoors that do not learn to hunt will not attack other prey pets. Cats and rabbits are good companions in the end so hope they stay close to each other!

Comment: If the rabbit would be afraid, it would run away. As I described, the rabbit assumes itself as winner of the fight, and to be honest, rabbits can cause bad injuries in cats with their teeth, and they are not afraid to use them.