# Why do my pets eat at the same time I eat?

Tags: behavior, eating

I recently noticed that my pets (indoor rabbit and a parakeet) almost always eat at the moment I start eating my breakfast or dinner. I was wondering, is there a reason for this?

Comment: What is your rabbit eating when you eat?  If it is hay, they should be eating some every hour or two, and have it always available.  If it is pellets they are probably getting to many pellets when you feed them.  See related [What are the basic requirements of a healthy adult rabbit's diet?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1460)

Comment: My rabbit is mostly eating dry food, not hay at the time I eat. However, after a few minutes he stops. Like seeing / hearing me eating something triggers him to start eating as well.

Comment: Some rabbits do well with free access to dry food at all times others do not.  Take a look at [this post](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-is-wool-block-in-rabbits/720#720) the brown rabbit was allowed to much dry food it caused significant harm to him. If your rabbit has a dewlap there may be cause for concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pets that graze throughout the day thus having higher chances of eating at the same time as you. It makes sense for them to be hungry first thing in the morning as well.

I have 3 parrots that do everything simultaneously - eat, groom, sleep and get scared. It's internal clockwork and flock mentality.