# What is a "bunny burrito" and when would I use it?

Tags: rabbits, grooming

I have heard about rabbit owners using a "bunny burrito" as part of their rabbit grooming process.

What is it?

How and when should it be used?

Comment: This is something new to me.  I wonder if it a UK Thing.

Comment: @Chad, it is not just a UK thing, also used on cats, you wrap the rabbit or cat in a towel.  Often with someone else holding the wrapped pet and extract one paw at a time for nail clipping.  Do you have a different name for it?

Comment: Wrapping in a towel :p

Comment: LOL, How unimaginative what a boring group you hang out with.

Comment: with (human) babies it is called swaddling

Comment: There are lots of hints about the answer in the comments here, new users are encouraged to create an answer, using the comments as start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I trance my rabbit?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/how-do-i-trance-my-rabbit)

Comment: Not a duplicate; Completely different solutions to a similar problem.

Comment: Wrong, in that post you mention the uses of bunny burrito in grooming: "Trimming nails and grooming the stomach area when needed are activities that must be done. A bunny-burrito, sedation and TI are all options." If you want a different answer, you should revise your question to include include the knowledge you already have and ask for more specifics. The fact you know the answer to the question you posted, but then failed to answer your own question, leaving others to possibly waist time on it reeks of sock puppetry.

Comment: @Virtualxtc - I think the question is fine.  The point is to have the content here to be found if someone searches for it.  This is a softball for someone who knows the answer feel free to knock it out of the park.

Answer (score 6):

Bunny burrito should really be called bunny enchilada; it's when you wrap up the bunny up tightly in a towel so that only its face and tail stick out, thereby restricting it's ability to use it's legs.

It's most commonly used when force feeding medicine and inspecting oral hygiene and genitals.

Bunny burrito usually is not used for grooming, but could be effective if one needed to focus grooming on an area near the tail or face, however, putting a bunny on a low traction waist-high table, or holding it against your chest, or just petting it with all "4 on the floor" are all preferred of this more stressful technique.  Contrary to the information in [this answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/how-do-i-trance-my-rabbit/1863#1863), it is not possible to use bunny burrito for belly grooming as exposing the belly would also leave the bunny's legs mobile.

Bunny burrito could potentially be used for nail trimming by loosening one edge of the towel just enough so that a paw my be removed and individual addressed.  However, the bunny trance method, while considered equally stressful, provides faster quicker access to the rabbits paws and thus is preferred by rabbit care professionals.  Moreover, professionals recommend owners try the table method first as it's least stressful for the rabbit.