# When should I cut my bunny’s nails?

Tags: rabbits

So I just adopted a 2 month old Netherland dwarf and I have no idea when to cut his nails. His nails look like this currently so I’m unsure if I should just let the vet cut his nails, or if his nails are just supposed to be this long.

[image: my 2 month old bunnies nails]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! :) because of the fur it is not easy to see how long the nails are. Please add a picture of one footh only :) You are lucky, because the fur is white, and so the nails are white too. There you can see through the red/blue blood vessels inside. The distance between them and the end of the nail is your measurement when you need to cut the nails.

Comment: And please think about the option to adopt a second bunny. Because even if the human tries the best, humans can not substitute a rabbit friend. Please see this question for details :) [Bunny alone - good idea?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25974/bunny-alone-good-idea) At your picture I can see, that your bunny will have much space. This is great for this happy moving animal :D

Answer (score 5):

To decide when to cut the nails of your rabbit, you can use a rule of thumb: if the nails are longer than the surrounding fur, you should have a closer look to them. (If your rabbit has special/non-natural fur, like rex or teddy, this rule does not work) In average this is between 3 and 12 weeks after the last cut.

If you pick up your rabbit, you should choose a position with good control about it and good view onto the feet for you. There are two recommendations about the positions: One with the bunny is "sitting" like a baby (its back onto your front) and the second with the bunny sitting across your legs, front feet on one leg, back feet on the other leg. If your rabbit is nervous and moves a lot, you can use a blanket/towel to lay it on it's eyes. Some people swear onto the "rabbit burrito" (have a look for related questions [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/what-is-a-bunny-burrito-and-when-would-i-use-it)) but I did not used it until now.

[image: Position one]

You should have a nail-clipping tool which is made for animals, because human nail clippers will be not strong enough to cut the nails, and are supposed to be used on well behaving, not twitchy humans.

Then you have a look to each single nail. If the fur is white, you will see the nerve and blood vessel inside the nail with ease, if it is dark, you can use a torch/flashlight to flash through the nail and detect the nerve.

[image: Nail cutting guide]

As you can see in the picture, your first aim is to not injure the nerve and blood vessel. The second aim is to shape the cutting in a way, the nail is as natural as possible. The cutting should be parallel to the ground (if you imagine the foot standing on a plain surface) and the cuttings at the same foot should be approximately plain too. The first aim (not cut the nerve) is more important than the second, especially, when you are a beginner.

In case you have cut the nerve accidentally, you should use disinfection onto it. Choose a dry and clean underground for your bunny, until some additional time, after the blood dried.

In case your bunny had have too long nails for some time, the nerve would grow longer too. When you start to cut the nails, you would orientate at the nerve, instead the length of the fur. And after some time of proper cutting the nerve will grow shorter again.

(source: photo and knowledge from [www.kaninchenwiese.de](https://www.kaninchenwiese.de/pflege/krallen-schneiden/) in German)

Answer (score -1):

I'm in 4-H and I do my rabbits nails once every two weeks. Although I handle mine daily and I don't like being scratched. It really depends on how often you handle it and how fast the nails grow. I'm not saying never cut their nails. But once a month would be just fine or once a week. Depending on how often you wanna do it. If you do it once a week it isn't worth it. It barely grows. I've got a Himilayan doe (female) and a Mini Rex buck (male) one needs their nails trimmed every two weeks and another once a month. The more you do it the easier it will be. If you have difficulties with nail trimming figure out their favorite treat (make sure it's something they can eat carrots and spring mix lettuce are the common favorites in my rabbits.) Avoid iceberg lettuce. Rabbits are very sensitive and cannot regurgitate foods that their digestive system didn't like. So make sure that what your giving you bun bun is healthy. Rabbits tend to show signs of illness very late. Due to the fact that wild rabbits will get kicked out of the burrow or safe place if they show signs of illness. The last thing you want is a sick bunny! I hope this helps!