# My bunny will not stop kicking her litter out of her litter box, what do I do?

Tags: behavior, training, rabbits, toilet-training

I got bunny and she is an inside bunny. Well, she will not stop kicking her litter out of her litter box. I would like for her to stay an inside bunny, but my dad said if I do not get her to stop, she will have to go outside. How do I get her to stop, because I do not want to put her outside?

Comment: What kind of litter does you use? Wood-pellets, Straw? And how is the litter box shaped? Low or high walls? If low, you could try first to use a box with high walls, or even one with a "roof" and only one opening to get in and out

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in a general way (I will provide more detail, when you have answered my comment)

The litter should be comfortable for the rabbit. Many rabbits like a **"soft" cover**, for example straw or paper shavings at the top. You could try to cover your usual litter with this. Some rabbits even like to take a nap onto this "bedding" and only use one corner to defecate.

The litter box need to be the **right size**. The rabbit should be able to lay (with long hind legs) comfortable in it.

And there are litter boxes, which help you with their **shape**. For example a litter box for cats shaped with a roof (see the picture for example) will help. Then the rabbit can rearrange the litter inside, until it is comfortable with it, but the litter will not spread onto the outside.

[image]

For this box I would propose to install some kind of step for the rabbit to get in. This could be a piece of a thick branch or some kind of brick. (The important: the surface should be not slippery, and it should be stable.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons that come to my mind:

1. The litter is dirty and your rabbit is trying to dig to improve her toilet. Check her litter more frequently, and change it more often if it's dirty.
2. She wants to dig because her claws are long. Check her claws and trim them if they are long. Locate the quick (the live red tissue within her nails) and measure the distance to the tip of her nails. Consult a vet as to what that length should be.
3. She just yearns to dig. Take her outside to dig, or just let her have at it.
4. She is bored and being destructive. Give her something else to destroy like a box or stick to chew on, or a blanket to dig on.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Thank you for your answer, but it could be much improved if you at least mentioned a few "obvious solutions" to the problems you listed. People often come here because they have little experience or the first solution they tried didn't actually solve their problem.

Comment: Good advice. Please see the update.

Comment: For you interest: cutting rabbit's nails https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29717/when-should-i-cut-my-bunny-s-nails

Comment: FYI rabbit digging box: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/my-rabbit-is-digging-at-the-carpet-in-the-corner-of-the-living-room-what-should

Comment: @Allerleirauh That's good. I trim my rabbits' nails, but I'm too nervous to write up advice. One piece of good advice I've gotten: before you clip, apply a little pressure. The rabbit will jump if it's too close to her quick.

Comment: Carly Green, I like your idea, "She doesn't like your litter-- try using recycled paper pellets," but that should be a comment or an answer. You, not I, deserve credit for it.