# Airlines that allow rabbits in cabin, intl flight

Tags: rabbits

We are moving to the US from France. I'm not comfortable using a pet relocation service. Are there any airlines that allow rabbits as carry on in cabin? The flight is about 6-7 hrs. They're 2 well binded rabbits that can comfort each other. The longest they've been in a cage is 3 hrs at a stretch.

Comment: Which airlines could you use for your flight? There are several that allow rabbits. But which would you take?

Comment: FYI : Rabbits as hand luggage https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/rabbits-as-hand-luggage-in-airplane

Comment: Also interesting: oversea relocation of rabbit https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/32753/how-stressful-is-an-overseas-relocation-for-a-rabbit/32798#32798

Comment: That's the thing. I have contacted Air France and Delta. Both refused to let rabbits in the cabin. I want to know of someone knows of an airlines that will allow that.

Comment: searching for "fly europe to us rabbit" I found the following link, no experience myself (beneath the linked questions above) https://www.petsthattravel.com/airlines-that-allow-rabbits-in-cabin/

Comment: In case you managed to have your rabbit in the cabin, please answer the question yourself :) this is fine here and would help other users later on!

Comment: Thanks for the link. None of them have direct flights from France to US. I'll let you know if I find any!