# International travel with cockatiel bird

Tags: birds, cockatiels

I am travelling internationally from US to middle east as a round trip. Do you know which airlines accept birds in the passenger cabin?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more suited to Travel SE

Comment: Related, because it explains the guidelines of airplane flights with pets: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/rabbits-as-hand-luggage-in-airplane

Answer (score 1):

Did some research as this wasn't immediately obvious to me.

First, you have to find an airline that will even allow you to do that. There are multiple options but none of the ones I found regularly fly outgoing flights to the U.S other than returning the planes, which you can still board, but that's not the point.

The airline I found was Delta. I know. I just said Delta.

International travel with a pet bird can be complicated and requires careful planning. Depending on the type of bird you have or the destination country, you may need to obtain various permits, certificates, and documents before your trip. You may also need to follow quarantine and health regulations to ensure the safety of your bird and prevent the spread of diseases. Some airlines allow pet birds to travel in the cabin or the cargo hold, but others may not accept them at all. You should contact your airline directly or visit their official website to review their current policies and procedures for flying with birds. You should also check the requirements of your destination country and any stopover countries on your itinerary, as they may differ from the U.S. regulations.

Here are some general tips to help you prepare for your international travel with your pet bird:

- Make sure your bird is healthy and fit for travel. Consult your veterinarian and obtain a health certificate and a vaccination record for your bird. You may also need to get a microchip or a leg band for identification purposes.
- Obtain the necessary permits and documents for your bird. Depending on the species and origin of your bird, you may need to apply for a CITES permit, a USDA APHIS export permit, a U.S. Fish and Wildlife Service declaration form, and/or an import permit from the destination country. You should also check if your bird needs a passport or a pet travel scheme (PETS) certificate.
- Prepare a suitable carrier or crate for your bird. The carrier or crate should be spacious, comfortable, secure, and well-ventilated. It should also have food, water, and toys for your bird. You should label the carrier or crate with your contact information and a “Live Animal” sticker. You should also familiarize your bird with the carrier or crate before the trip.
- Plan your travel itinerary carefully. You should avoid traveling during extreme weather conditions, peak seasons, or busy hours. You should also allow enough time for check-in, security, customs, and quarantine procedures. You should also inform the airline staff and the airport authorities that you are traveling with a pet bird and follow their instructions.
- Monitor your bird’s condition and behavior during and after the trip. You should check on your bird regularly and make sure it is comfortable and calm. You should also look for any signs of stress, illness, or injury and seek veterinary attention if needed. You should also follow the quarantine and health regulations of the destination country and report any problems to the authorities.

I hope this information helps you plan your international travel with your pet bird.

I wish you and your feathery friend a safe and enjoyable trip. I'm heading to Nevada tomorrow, so you're not the only one who's travelling!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, transporting pets by air is better avoided if at all possible, especially  across national borders due to the quarantine (and possibly protected-species) laws others have mentioned. Since you say this will be a round trip, I would suggest finding someone willing to take care of your bird while you are away from home.