# How can I take care of a bunny?

Tags: rabbits, feeding

So here is the deal: my dad purchased a baby bunny (or at least I think so, because it is really small) for my sister.

But considering my previous experience, I know I will end up taking care of it. If anyone could give me information on how to take care of it, or could lead me to a trusted information site, it would be very helpful.

Thank you.

---

**Update edit**

Thank you very much, I have improved its living space, I have prepared an instruction manual for feeding it, built a water dispenser and played with it quite a lot. Regarding the topic of getting another rabbit - I was thinking that I should introduce him to a female or another male.  I haven't neutered him yet, but I plan to do it this week. Thank you for all the feedback and your support.

Comment: RE: Update.  You might want to look at these two question [Introducing male rabbit to girl rabbit](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10449) & [What causes rabbits to spontaneously change gender?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11064)  Be aware it is a lot of really hard work to have two rabbits be friends. [we have a couple questions here](http://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brabbits%5D+bonding) if you have more questions please post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

By the time rabbits are weaned and ready to be placed in homes, they are usually nearly (~75%) of their full size.  If the bunny is small it is likely a dwarf breed.

You have found one of the better sites on internet for bunny information.

You might start by reviewing all the questions [tagged rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits)

If you don't have much experience with rabbits here are some good questions and answers to start with.

- [Can rabbits fart?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1503)
- [What is wool block in rabbits?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/692)
- [Can a bath really kill a rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1853)
- [How much space does a rabbit need to live comfortably?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1962)

Many of these include links to good references, and related questions. If you have any other questions and find we don't already have an answer to it, post a new question.

Comment: It's a nice welcoming to the site, but that's all it is. There minimal effort to answer the question, links are not gonna die, but they should include what's most important of them.

Comment: @JustDoIt the links in this answer are all internal. If they don't work this answer won't be here any more, the whole site will be gone.  You are correct, including the relevant parts of external links is critical to a good answer.  This is the case in the answers to the linked questions.

Comment: Thats what I meant by *links are **not** gonna die, **but** they should include what's most important of them*

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad to hear you are prepared to take responsibility for this bunny.  So many rabbits are bought as children's pets without proper research!

Rabbits are social animals, and live in groups in the wild.  Single isolated rabbits can become very depressed.  This rabbit will need either lots of human company and stimulation, or ideally a bunny friend to keep him company.

Rabbits need a lot more space than people tend to think.  The small cages sold for them are really only suitable as bedrooms.  A rabbit should either be let out every day to run in a rabbit proofed room or run, or ideally, have a run as well as a house to sleep in that is at least six foot square and in which it can stand up fully on hind legs.

The pelleted rabbit food is not great for their teeth, although it's better for them than the sort of food that has lots of brightly-coloured chunks and grains in it.   Ideally, your rabbit should be eating as much grass and hay as possible. Don't use sawdust for bedding, it's murder on their lungs and not that easy to clean out.

Rabbits love to chew and because their teeth grow constantly, they need to do it a lot.  Cardboard boxes to destroy are often popular, and you can buy nests made from untreated woven grasses or willow.  If you know anyone with an apple tree, your rabbit will love cuttings from that to chew, and they are usually available free when the tree needs pruning!

Rabbits are very hormonal animals, and they can get very grumpy if not spayed/neutered.  Female rabbits are also very prone to reproductive disorders, so it's best to get them neutered early so they can be introduced to a friend.

In my country (Britain) the diseases that require vaccination in rabbits are myxomatosis and RHD - but your country may be different, so consult your vet.

Rabbits can live up to 12 years if well looked after.  Ideally they will live indoors, but they can be somewhat messy and destructive companions in small spaces, being hard to completely house train,  so in warmer countries without too many nasty predators, they are often kept outside. This is sometimes considered controversial, but in my opinion is OK if the rabbit has plenty of space and company, has a well insulated dry space, for example a shed, to sleep,  and is not exposed to predators or disease.

It is NOT OK to keep a single rabbit outside in a small hutch where it will be lonely and vulnerable to predators.

I hope that helps.  Try the Rabbit Welfare Association website for more.