# My female rabbit is failing to give birth, the bunnies die right after they are delivered

Tags: rabbits, breeding, reproduction

My doe is unable to give birth, the bunnies die just right after they are delivered.

Is something wrong with my doe's womb?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. To answer your question it is important that you give more information. What age/race/health ist your rabbit? How long was she pregnant? How did she live? Do you go to a vet with her? Was it a planned birth or did it surprise you she was even pregnant? In all cases with the health of our animals: go to the vet and do not wait for the meanings of some strangers from the internet!

Comment: `"unable to give birth"` is very misleading. What you describe is that she gives birth just fine, but the bunnies just do not survive. They are two very different topics.

Comment: See also [Why are my Baby bunnies Dying?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/12208/13) and [My rabbit just had babies and they are dying. What can I do?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/7417/13)

Comment: Related Question: [How to act, if the mothers seems not to feed the babies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31540/my-rabbit-isn-t-feeding-her-baby-what-should-i-do)