# What is Rabbit Mash and how is it useful for challenged rabbits?

Tags: health, diet, rabbits, cooked-food

I read something about mash for rabbits.

What is it made with? How to prepare it? In which cases is it useful?

Answer (score 3):

**Rabbit Mash**

My senior rabbit has problems with maintaining her weight, so I explored this on [kaninchenwiese.de](https://www.kaninchenwiese.de/ernaehrung/futtermittel/nahrungsergaenzungsmittel/mash-fuer-kaninchen/).

It works for rabbits that need **more energy** because they are:

- outside in the winter (low temperatures, beneath 0°C)
- (chronically) ill
- seniors
- lactating or pregnant
- big breeds

But one must be aware that in the long run, health issues could arise. If the rabbit eats the mash only, for example, the food-grinding would be missed, which causes the teeth to grow longer than usual.

And (even if you want your rabbit to gain weight) it should be fed in **low doses**. Around 1 full teaspoon for one kilogram of rabbit daily is enough. (This would be 2 full teaspoons for a 2 kg dwarf rabbit senior per day.)

Possible **ingredients**:

- oil seeds (sunflower, chia seeds, sorghum bicolor, hemp seed, pumpkin seeds, flax seed, poppy seed, sesame) *they support the digestive system and help with fur issues*
- flour seeds (amaranth, buckwheat, spelt seeds, barley seeds, grass seeds, oats, sorghum, corn/maize, quinoa) *in general grains need to be fed with spelt to be healthy*
- aromatic seeds (aniseed, nettle seeds, dill seeds, fennel seed, coriander, caraway, milk thistle seeds) *they have lots of positive active components*
- bran *a common food for horses*
- dried herbs (examples: basil, dill, thyme, sage, chives, oregano, marjoram, parsley, chamomile, coriander, rosemary, peppermint) *ready mixes for rabbits, or self made mixes for special aims like supporting the digestive system or the breathing*
- immune supporting additives, like drops/powder from the shop or ginger (ginger needs slow, slow, slow habituation, but has a positive effect to the immune system proven by research)
- fruits (any of your rabbit's preferred kinds, grated) *mine loves apple and carrot, raisins sometimes*

Example for a **recipe** from the linked website (above)

- one cup crushed oat (with spelt)
- one cup crushed flax seeds
- 4 cups herb mix

My mix for my senior rabbit (with chronic common colds):

- <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> cup flax seed
- <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> cup sesame seed
- <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> cup oat flakes
- <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> cup sunflower seeds (without spelt)
- 4 cups of dried kitchen herbs (basil, thyme, marjoram, parsley, chive and dill)
- Sometimes I grind <sup>1</sup>/<sub>8</sub> apple or carrot into the mix, or cut 4 raisins into very small pieces, to vary the taste.

*I buy these ingredients in a supermarket, because I am limited in my options to buy other seeds and dried herbs where I live*

**Preparation**

I mix the whole cups (without fresh food like apple/carrot) together into a closable plastic food storage box. Each day I take two teaspoons full of the mix out of it.

[image: raw ingredients]

Then I crush the mix in a mortar, while waiting for the water to boil.

[image: crushed seeds]

I mix the crushed components with warm water (between 30 and 50°C) and let them soak and swell for around 30 minutes.

[image: water-seed-mix]

*The first few times I needed to experiment with how much water is needed. One can use a little bit at first and then add some until the consistency is like baby food.*

[image: final mash]

I serve this mix on a small plate to my senior, but in extreme cases it is possible to feed it with a syringe too. If you have **rabbits who should not gain weight** in addition to your rabbit, then you may need to separate them for around one hour. My senior defends her plate against her husband, so I do not need this. But maybe your rabbit is not powerful enough to do so.