# Help guinea pig recover from bad impaction

Tags: health, defecation, guinea-pigs, digestion

So, my guinea pig has been acting very sick for 2 or 3 days, and today we noticed he had a huge impaction. We think he may have had it for a few weeks, but just noticed when he started acting very differently. We removed it (or at least 95% of it), but we are concerned that it may have been too late for him to fully recover. Is there anything we should do to help him recover? Thanks!

Edit- I just remembered he has been getting these jerking spasms too during this, thought that may be important.

Comment: Photo would be helpful.

Comment: Of what? He just looks like a sick guinea pig. For the past 2 or 3 days he has been lying around not moving much, so what I'm saying is what should I do to help him get back to his happy, active old self

Comment: impaction seems to describe two issues, one of the digestive system and one issue with the teeth. Which one is yours? And how did you remove it? What caused it? Please visit a vet, if you are in worry about the health of your pet, instead of waiting for guesses from strangers out of the internet :)

Comment: I'm talking about digestive system kind. A large ball of poo in his anal sack. You remove it by carefully squeezing and prodding it out. Not sure what caused it, it seems to be quite common with older guinea pigs. The problem is that we didn't catch it in time. Everyone says that by the time he gets this bad, it's usually too late, but they do get better some times. He is still not getting better, so we may take him to the vet today.

Comment: +1 for visiting the vet. please write an update or answer after it! In general you could search for "helping" food. There are some kinds of seeds, helping with digestion, but I am not sure, how they would correlate with impaction... Also you could prepare special mash to make eating more easy for the guinea pig. I will add a link to an realted question about rabbit mash, you could proove the ingredients and change the ones, not suited for guinea pigs. But the principle of preparation would be the same.

Comment: [Mash for Rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29938/what-is-rabbit-mash-and-how-is-it-useful-for-challenged-rabbits?r=SearchResults)

Comment: He didnt make it. :(  We were gonna take him to the vet at 4:45 yesterday, he died at 4:15.

Comment: I am sad to read this. I wish you all the best :(