# Just rescued a bunny... Not eating any hay or rabbit food

Tags: rabbits

My mom rescued a bunny that was abandoned in a house for about 9 months, and we got her a nice big cage, with plenty of chews, and lots of hay and rabbit food. Our neighbor was feeding the bunny, but she could never catch her and she ate her food them but she isn't anymore. I've had her for 3 days, and yesterday I gave her half a carrot and about 2 or 3 broccoli. I mixed her regular Timothy pellets (her regular food she isn't eating) with Timothy hay (also something she isn't eating) with some dry oats and the carrot and broccoli. She ate everything except her pellets and hay. I know she needs to say both of them, but I'm not sure how to get her to want to eat them. What should I do??

Answer (score 2):

To get her to eat more hay, feed less pellets and carrots.  A better choice for fresh vegetables is romaine lettuce.

Carrots and broccoli should both be feed with moderation [What to Feed Your Rabbit at rabbit.org](http://rabbit.org/what-to-feed-your-rabbit/) also see [Are carrots a healthy part of a rabbit diet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1816)

Pellets should also be feed in moderation, about 1/4 cup per pounds of body weight per day (but varies greatly depending on weight issues).

As the rabbit was outside for some time, fleas may be an issue, so take a look at [How do I get rid of fleas on my rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/925)