# My hedgehog is almost completely immobile and won't eat, what can I do?

Tags: health, feeding, hedgehog

For the past few days, my hedgehog has been almost completely immobile. She was able to slowly wobble around a cage for a day, but now is only able to curl slightly (but not fully), and wiggle her nose. She's been just lying on her side for around 2 days now, and doesn't seem at all interested in food (although she still drinks water if I put her head in her water dish).

She doesn't make any noises indicating that she's in pain or anything, she just lies there. The only odd thing I've noticed (besides her not moving) is that her eyes seem to have a blue tinge to them, and keep twitching.

I wasn't able to take her to the vet when it first started, and now, she's looking rough enough that I'm not sure that they can do anything. I don't have enough money currently to take her in just so they can look at her (I've heard that can be upwards of $100).

Do these symptoms match anything treatable, or should I start looking into more unfortunate options?

[image: Hedgehog laying on its side]
(Her lying on her side)

[image: Closeup of hedgehog's eye]
(Close-up of her eye. I couldn't get a good picture of the blue, as it's around the outside of her eye, and only shows when they're bulged a bit. They've always seemed slightly blue, but it seems to be more pronounced now)

**Additional information:**

I'm guessing she's around 5 years old. She was quite small when I got her, and I've had her for around 2 years. She eats organic cat food (high protein and fiber, low fat), a "superfood" mix from safeway (kale, broccoli, cabbage), and freeze-dried super worms.

That has been her consistent diet for the past year and a half (she was on wet cat food before). She's never had any other problems, other then being very reclusive; although that seems to be a fairly common trait for hedgehogs.

Comment: Note: You're still going to want to consider a vet. Especially since there's no guarantee that you'll get an answer before it's late. Look into low cost vet clinics or vets that support payment plans if money is a concern.

Comment: How old is your hedgehog? Does she have any past medical issues?  What foods have you been feeding? Have you made any changes to her diet recently?

Comment: @James Jenkins I'm guessing she's around 5. She was quite small when I got her, and I've had her for around 2 years. She eats organic cat foot (high protein and fiber, low fat), a "superfood" mix from safeway (kale, broccoli, cabbage), and freeze dried super worms. That has been her consistent diet for the past year and a half (she was on wet cat food before). She's never had any other problems, other then being very reclusive; although that seems to be a fairly common trait for hedgehogs.

Comment: It looks like the [life expectancy is upwards of 16 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog#Reproduction_and_lifespan) kale, broccoli, cabbage are all high contributors to gas. As pointed out in this rabbit questions [One of the recognized treatments for gas in rabbits is Simethicone, an anti-foaming agent that helps in the passing of gas](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/can-rabbits-fart/1508#1508).  While going to the vet is the number one option here, giving gas drops is the first next best thing. All but the sickest rabbits will drink good flavored brand from a spoon.

Comment: I found a vet, so I'm taking her after work. And thanks. She doesn't make any noises that you'd expect from pain though. The only sound I've heard her make is a sneeze if I accidently dunk her nose in the water.

Comment: Just an update. There is a single exotic vet clinic in my city that is able to see him, but they don't have any open spots until Wednesday unfortunately. She's almost exactly as she has been the past couple days; if not slightly better. She still refuses any food, but is still drinking plenty of water. She still can't/won't walk, but is now at least able to move herself around her bed to get comfortable (I found her in a ball this morning, facing the opposite direction that I left her in). I gave her a bath, and ran some warm water over her belly, which caused her to fart.

Comment: As a "why not" measure, I've started her on simethicone, but it doesn't seem to have done anything yet. She doesn't like taking liquids from a dropper (she seems to choke), so I just had her lap it up from a spoon, but she didn't get much.

Comment: I managed to get an appointment for Saturday evening. Later then I'd like, but better then Wednesday.

Comment: Simethicone sounds good. To fight of dehydration, you can also offer her pedialyte or gatorade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I took her to the vet. It ended up being [WHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wobbly_hedgehog_syndrome); a disease comparable to MS in humans. It's incurable, and she was euthanized :(.

Sorry if this is the case for anyone else.

Comment: Condolences on your loss.

Comment: Thank you. At least she's not suffering anymore.

Comment: this is so sad. so sorry for fer. Sorry