# How can I get my rabbit to eat different greens?

Tags: diet, rabbits

I understand that rabbits are supposed to get a variety of greens in their diet, however, my rabbit only eats dandelions. We have tried to give her parsley, and no matter what, she just lets them sit there. Is there anything I can do to get her to eat different greens?

Comment: Rabbits actually do better on a consistent diet that is primarily hay and pellets with occasional greens as a treat.  Is there a specific reason you are wanting to get your rabbit to eat other greens?

Comment: @Critters some [sources](http://rabbit.org/what-to-feed-your-rabbit/) recommend feeding greens in quantity daily.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - And I have previously voiced my concerns about the inaccuracies and dangerous opinions that are listed at rabbit.org.  especially since that list includes Broccoli and Brussel sprouts which are both dangerous due to their tendency to produce gas in the gut.

Comment: @Critters I concur that not all of the diet suggestions at rabbit.org are the best choices, but I am unaware of any one site that is better. There is a large gap in the diet knowledge for long term house rabbit care.  Most research is short term production rabbit diet info. Do you have any good sources, for fresh greens as a part of the daily diet for rabbits living in the 8 to 12 year range? If you have good data, I would be happy to write the question, for you to answer.

Comment: to the point broccoli and Brussel sprouts: they are not dangerous, when the rabbits do not get grains in their daily diet. The gas builds only if the starch part of food is too high. In nature the rabbits get starch (corn, grains) only in autumn for some weeks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dandelions are a number one favorite of most everybunny I have met. When changing diet, it is important not to make rapid changes [Do I need to do anything special when I change what I feed my rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1441)

Having tossed out those two bits of wisdom...

When introducing a new vegetable in the diet we tend to replace about 10 - 25% of the green being served with the new item.  Roman lettuce is the foundation of the fresh greens we feed, in our grocery stores it is available year round, for reasonable price.

My recommendation is mix some Romain lettuce in with the dandelions, and leave them for your bunny to explore and taste.  If delivered as part of the regular meal, the rabbit should taste and probably eat them all within a couple hours.

Everybunny is an individual with different tastes. We have had several bunnies in the house turn up their nose at one green or another, but never had one refuse Romain.

Comment: FWIW Dandelions are very mild, good for the gut, and one of the first greens a bunny can eat.  I suspect this is part of the reason that bunnies love them.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbits have favorite tastes like humans too.

But another point is this: rabbits are smart. They try a tiny bit of new food they do not know and then wait for around one day. If they stay healthy and have no problems, then they eat the whole food.

Maybe you replaced the food before they could complete their "test", so they could not decide to eat the whole parsley.